# How to sort a mixed-typed list?

Tags: python

I have a list that looks as follows (the 'None' in the list is a string, not a None):

```
profit = [1  , 20 , 3  , 5  , 90 , 'None', 900, 67 , 'None'] 
name   = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'e', 'd', 'f'   , 'g', 'k', 'pp']
```

The `profit` list is a list of "profit" values, so I had to sort it in a reversed order so that the highest values will be at the beginning.

Also, I have more lists with the same length that represent other things that are connected to the `profit` list (for example the `name` list that shows where the profit came from).

Now, I wrote the following code to sort the `profit` list in a reversed order, and I save the indices so I could sort the other lists (like `name`) according to the obtained indices:

```
sorted_ind = sorted(range(len(profit)), key=lambda k: profit[k], reverse=True)
for i in sorted_ind:
    print('{0:^50}|{1:^7}|'.format(profit[i], name[I]))
```

The above code works great when my `profit` list contains only numbers.
However, there are cases where I have no profit and I would like this value to be 'None' (I don't want to set it to 0).

I'm trying to perform the same sort but in a way that all of the None indices will be at the end of the list - to sort all the ints and insert the Nones at the end.

Any good way to do it?

Comment: Why is the string `'None'` preferable to a None value and to the numeric value zero? Seems an odd choice.

Comment: Because there are cases where I have minus values as well and if I use a zero and sort it will seem like a better result than the negative ones even though the None for me means like "not enough information" and I had like it to appear last.

Comment: `None`, `0` and `'None'` are 3 different things.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a "priority" `key` to the sort function which checks the types as well:

```py
>>> sorted(profit, key=lambda x: (isinstance(x, int), x), reverse=True)
[900, 90, 67, 20, 5, 3, 1, 'None', 'None']
```

---

If you're doing that just to sort the `names` list, then it is not necessary to sort the indices, you should use [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip):

```py
profits = [1, 20, 3, 5, 90, 'None', 900, 67, 'None']
names = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'e', 'd', 'f', 'g', 'k', 'pp']

sorted_ind = sorted(zip(profits, names), key=lambda tup: (isinstance(tup[0], int), tup[0]), reverse=True)
for profit, name in sorted_ind:
    print('{0:^50}|{1:^7}|'.format(profit, name))
```

Gives:

```
                       900                        |   g   |
                        90                        |   d   |
                        67                        |   k   |
                        20                        |   b   |
                        5                         |   e   |
                        3                         |   c   |
                        1                         |   a   |
                       None                       |   f   |
                       None                       |  pp   |
```

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing magical about "lambda": it's just a way of spelling a simple Python function without giving it a name. With a fancier function, you could check the value at index `k` and *use* 0 for sorting instead if it happens to be `"None"`. Which can be squashed into a "lambda" but is clearer if you use a regular function:

```
def keyfunc(i):
    val = profit[i]
    return 0 if val == "None" else val
```

So add that, and pass `key=keyfunc`. Done! :-)

### CAUTION

If you use a unique value to indicate "don't care" (your question used the string `"None"`, but you *probably* really want the Python special value `None`, or even `math.nan` instead), then a key function is - as above - easy to write with no surprises. And instead of returning 0 for "don't care", you *probably* want to return `-math.inf` instead.

But if you check on type instead (as a different answer suggested), the code becomes more delicate. For example, if you ever have a floating-point profit (like 13.75), checking for type `int` will treat it as "don't care" instead. Type checks are broad and brittle. There are quite a few numeric types that can be meaningfully compared to ints.

So it's generally better (more robust and clearer) to use a special value instead.